# Solve $\sqrt{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}} + \sqrt{\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}} = x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My teacher gave a hint: **Let $z = F(x) + G(y)$ and use separation of variables**, but I think if I can let $z = F(x) + G(y)$, then it seems that $\sqrt{\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}}$ this term won't appear $x$, so this is an ODE and I don't need separation of variables.

Also I don't know how to use separation of variables if those things I said upon was wrong.

Can anyone help me or give me some hint? Thanks~

Comment: If you follow the advice of your teacher, you will see that the first term on the left and the term on the right are independent of $y$. Hence the second term on the left is also independent of $y$ and must be constant, say $C$. The rest is easy.

Comment: @M.Wind I did what you said, and I encountered a little problem. I find that $F'(x) = x^2$ and $G'(y) = C$, after integrating I got $z = Cy + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + c_2$ ($c_2$ is from integrating over $F'(x)$). And I put it into the problem and find $C = 0$. Is that right?

Comment: Maple answers $u\! \left(x,y\right)=\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\sqrt{\textit{_}c_{2}}\, x^{2}+\textit{_}c_{2} x+\textit{_}\mathit{C1}+\textit{_}c_{2} y+\textit{_}\mathit{C2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is an exercise into the technique of separation of variables. So let us follow the advice of the teacher, and assume that we can write $z = F(x) + G(y)$.

Substitute this expression into the differential equation. We get $\sqrt {F'(x)} +\sqrt{G'(y)} = x$. We observe that the first term on the left and the term on the right are independent of $y$. Therefore the second term on the left must also be independent of $y$, and hence constant; let us say $C$.

Bring $C$ to the right hand side. Then square both sides, to get rid of the square root. We get:

$$dF(x)/dx = (x-C)^2$$

Integration yields $F(x) = \frac {x^3}{3} -Cx^2 +C^2x +D $. Add to this $G(y)$ and we get the final result:

$$z = F(x) + G(y) = \frac {x^3} {3} - Cx^2 + C^2x + C^2y +D$$

This solution is not valid everywhere, due to taking two square roots. We can verify that the solution presented here holds when $C \ge 0$ and $x \ge C$.